# How can I enable SSL for Kubernetes services?

Tags: spring-boot, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a Google Kubernetes Engine with a spring boot application that has a public service endpoint. But I would like to change the endpoint from `http://...` to a secure `https://...` .

For example:
`https://xx.xxx.xx.xxxx:8085/getAllStudent` instead of `http://xx.xxx.xx.xxxx:8085/getAllStudent`

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using then NodePort type of your services. If you want to accept HTTPS over this port your service behind it simply needs to open a HTTPS server instead of an HTTP server.

Using NodePort like this is not a recommend way but rather use the proper [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/) functionality in Kubernetes in order to expose a service over a host name. Ingress then supports supplying an SSL certificate that can be used to encrypt traffic over HTTPS.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: tls-example-ingress
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - sslexample.foo.com
    secretName: testsecret-tls
  rules:
    - host: sslexample.foo.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: service1
            servicePort: 80
```